# Redirects in Nextjs config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a router, for example `/en/articles/[slug]` This slug depends on the locale. In the config I specify redirect `/de/articles/on-english/ => /de/articles/on-german/`

When I change the language I call `router.push(router.pathname, router.asPath, { locale: value })` So I get `/de/articles/on-english/`.

The problem is that the redirect works: but it redirects with a get parameter that shouldn't be there `/de/articles/on-german/?slug=on-english`

As a result, the url remains `/de/articles/on-english/`

If I redirect through middleware, everything works as it should.

What can be the problem?

Comment: What happens when you reach `/de/articles/on-german/?slug=on-english`? You get redirected to `/de/articles/on-english/` again?

Comment: What do you expect to happen without middleware? from the docs
"Redirects are not applied to client-side routing (Link, router.push), unless Middleware is present and matches the path."